# Ansible best tool for the job of adding and removing configurations to running applications?

Tags: tomcat, configuration, ansible

I'm new to Ansible and I see the advantages of using Ansible to get a bare server up and running with all the necessary software packages etc. However, I'm wondering if it's the correct tool for what I'm trying to do:

- I have a few servers (< 10) running Tomcat instances with multiple war applications
- for every customer a new war + configuration files are deployed
- for every customer that stops the service the war + config files are removed from the Tomcat server
- similarly: configurations are added/removed from an ini-formatted file
- I only want to add/remove the files and configuration for a specific customer and not touch the other configurations

Right now I'm using shell scripts to perform part of the work and the rest is manual, but it's error prone, so I'm looking for a better solution.

I can imagine an Ansible playbook for these tasks, but I don't see how I can make it work without constantly editing some file that defines which customer files need to be added/removed. That would make it at least as error prone as my shell scripts.

So I'm wondering if Ansible is suitable for the job or if there are better tools out there to be used for this specific need. And if there are better tools, which ones?

Comment: What did you settle on for managing configurations?  I'm in the same place, where I need to update them, and am wondering what to use.

Comment: For now, I've settled on creating specialised roles for managing one aspect of the configuration, e.g. a general update of the war file. For the deployment of a new customer I still rely on my old shell scripts. In the meantime I'm reworking the configuration so it's better suited for managing with Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single role that represents one customer. Have that role do the neccesary steps, and allow for anything that can be different between customers to be a variable.

You can set sane defaults for variables in the defaults file of a role, for example:

*role/defaults/main.yml:*

```
customer_name: ~
customer_war_file: "{{ customer_name }}.war"
```

*role/templates/server.config.j2:*

```
some_setting_x: {{ setting_x }}
some_setting_y: {{ setting_y }}
```

This way, you can use that role in a playbook over and over again:

```
- name: Playbook for customer deploys
  ...

  roles:
    - { role: my_deploy_role, customer_name: 'acme',  setting_x: 'foo', setting_y: 'bar' }
    - { role: my_deploy_role, customer_name: 'emca',  setting_x: 'bat', setting_y: 'baz' }
```

Expanding on that, you could add a setting that removes instead of deploys in your role - or if that gets too complicated, just create a separate role for removals:

```
  roles:
    - { role: my_deploy_role, customer_name: 'emca',  setting_x: 'bat', setting_y: 'baz' }
    - { role: my_remove_role, customer_name: 'acme' }
```

Keep in mind that the Ansible tasks are meant to be *idempotent*, meaning you can run them over and over with the same result. You should be **describing the state of the target system** as you want it to be after the script is done.

Most of Ansible's modules take care of that for you, for example if a *server.config.j2* template in the above example already exists on the target machine and is identical, Ansible will report "ok", not "changed".

If you're concerned about reloading a webserver when it's not needed, look into the [handlers](http://docs.ansible.com/glossary.html#handlers). Those are special tasks, only run when needed and run *after* your playbook is done.

Answer (score 0):

For editing ini files you could use http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/
With the soon to be released v0.5 you can trigger changes using the --verbose option like:

```
- command: crudini --set /your/config.ini section param value
  register: command_result
  changed_when: command_result.stderr | match("^changed")
```